# com.Jcraft.jsch.JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail while connecting to sftp in client location

Tags: java

when i am trying to connect to `SFTP` through jave code in client machine,I am getting the below exception, while using the Runnable jar in Client machine,
but in normal machine it's getting successfully connected to `SFTP`.

> JSchException: Algorithm negotiation fail

i am getting the exception here.

`session.connect();`

How to solve this?

Comment: Please post full stack trace, and relevant code. Also what do you mean by normal machine?

Comment: session = jsch.getSession(userName, hostName, 22);
session.setPassword(passWord);
Properties config=new Properties();
config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setConfig(config);
session.connect();

Comment: we have two environments,
one is local machine and another one is client machine.

Answer (score 0):

I too faced the same issue. We need to use the latest JSch library - jsch-0.1.54.jar.
After importing the latest jar, the problem was solved